# AWS learning with cassandra

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, amazon-keyspaces

I have just started learning AWS. Basically, I just want to know how AWS compatible and useful with Apache and Datastax Cassandra. What all the AWS things need to learn for Cassandra. Also, require to learn AWS internal architecture if I run Cassandra on AWS or just overview if anyone can help that will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS has [Amazon Keyspaces for Apache Cassandra](https://aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/) Service. That might be an option for you in this case.

Comment: It just has single region replication. It doesn't yet support multi region data centers.

Answer (score 1):

EC2, VPC, Subnet, Elastic IPs, Security Groups, EBS and RAID volumes are few. But it all depends on what you are trying to do? like are you going automate your installations, what would be your back up strategy etc.

Comment: Thanks GAK, Can you let me know or any link for Cassandra installation in AWS management console?